# What can be a different word for the use of 'obviously' when trying to make a clear statement?

Tags: word-choice

Just trying to find another word or term for when making a clear statement without sounding to arrogant.

For example, 'Obviously you shouldn't put your hand in a toaster because that's stupid'
(Not a practical example of what I'm working on, but shows my point'

Comment: The **obvious** should never need to be stated; therefore, there's no point but condescension when using the word the way you've used it in your "impractical example" sentence. OTOH, some people are cerebrally dense & others are distracted, so sometimes one needs to point out the obvious. When critiquing something or comparing two or more things, it's sometimes necessary & appropriate to point out what is obvious, but, as Uday Kanth says in his answer, "**clearly**" is usually not considered arrogant, except when tone of voice says otherwise. This is a better choice.

Comment: What are the options? Have you looked in a thesaurus? Which of those words have you considered and why don't they work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The word "Obviously" is not meant to sound arrogant but I'm afraid that these days you cannot say the word without sounding like you're condescending the other person. Why don't you just say "clearly". I think it sounds assertive without being arrogant.